# .NET 5 + Microsoft.Data.SqlClient - Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream

Tags: sql-server, ssl, .net-5

I updated my app from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5 and now I cant open a connection to my SQL Server database. The innermost exception error message is

> Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.

The top level error message is

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)

Other than the version of the .NET 5, I only updated the base image, from `3.1-bionic` to `5.0.3-focal-amd64`

Is there anything I'm also supposed to do?

**EDIT 1:**
I found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/default-cipher-suites-for-tls-on-linux#recommended-action) that seems closely related to what im going by. But after altering my `CipherString` to the values suggested, I got no change on the error. Same thing. Perhaps there's a `CipherString = ANY`?

Comment: Looks like it can't negotiate a TLS version with the server. What version of Windows is the server running?

Comment: Are you connecting to an older version of SQL Server? Probably there are differences in the `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` between `3.1-bionic` and `5.0.3-focal-am64` causing TLS 1.0 and/or 1.1 to be switched off in the latter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **NOTE**
>
> The Microsoft-recommended action is to improve security by upgrading your SQL Servers to support TLS v1.2

REFS:

- [SqlClient troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sqlclient-troubleshooting-guide#possible-reasons-and-solutions)
- [How to enable TLS 1.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2)
- [KB3135244 - TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe)

---

If, however, you are unable to upgrade your SQL Server to support TLS v1.2 you are able to influence the available ciphersuites to effect a downgrade of the client protocols negotiated by editing the `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` file.

Because Alpine containers are bare bones, start by installing your favorite editor, e.g.:

```sh
apt-get update
apt-get install nano
```

Edit your `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` to place the following line at the beginning of the file:

```
openssl_conf = default_conf
```

And the following lines at the end of the file:

```
########## Override default settings to enable TLS v1.0 and 1.1 ##########

[ default_conf ]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
#It really should be:
#CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=2
```

This will affect all openssl-enabled processes in the container. You can test connectivity before and after changes using the commands:

```sh
# Test TLS v1.0 connectivity
openssl s_client -host google.com -port 443 -tls1

# Test TLS v1.1 connectivity
openssl s_client -host google.com -port 443 -tls1_1
```