# SqlServer 2008R2 Connection Problem with SqlClient in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2008-r2

After upgrading from an older version of Entity Framework (core 3) to this one:

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/5.0.2`

I started getting a connection error only when I connect from my Docker container (in asp.net core. 5) to the remove SqlServer 2008R2.  When I do a test by creating a new sqlerver catalog on Azure and do the same connection test, I don't get the error (see below for error message).

Unfortunately, I'm working a hosting service that can not upgrade the 2008R2 and I know it's past end of life, but still hoping there is a work around I can use to get it working.  The host will not apply any new patches to the server (even if they were available because of the end of life status).

Below is my connection string that works connecting from my linux docker instance to sql azure but does not work when connecting to 2008R2.

```
Server=tcp:mysite.com,1433,1433;Initial Catalog=dbcatalog1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user1;Password={passwordhere};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

Here is the error I'm getting

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-08-07T
18:53:54.515357149Z"}
```

Comment: Not sure this is the root cause, but this `tcp:mysite.com,1433,1433` is wrong.  The port should not be specified twice.  It's likely that the server is forcing encryption but the client and server don't share any encryption suites.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, It actually wasn't in my real code but I double checked anyhow.  Still same problem.  I think it's related to this problem TLS 1.2 and linux. I don't want to downgrade TLS.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66445221/net-5-microsoft-data-sqlclient-received-an-unexpected-eof-or-0-bytes-from-t

Comment: Your SQL Server 2008R2 box may not have TLS 1.2.

Comment: Yes, it has TLS 1.2 set.

Answer (score 0):

It is a breaking change in the latest Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, set

```
Trust Server Certificate=true
```

Comment: Sadly, same error.  Here is my updated connection string.  Are there any docs you can point me at? I read that TrustServerCertificate comes with it's own requirements that I think I've met.  :Server=tcp:xxx.com,1433,1433;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xx;Password=xx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=true;Connection Timeout=30;

Comment: BTW @ErikEJ, I did find an issue you commented on https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/690 and I tried to remove the port 1433 (just leaving it out), but I still get the same error.

Comment: and then I think this is almost my exact issue, but the odd thing is that I do have tls 1.2 installed on my server.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66445221/net-5-microsoft-data-sqlclient-received-an-unexpected-eof-or-0-bytes-from-t

Comment: I think your server must be running SP4