# OperationalError when trying to connect to SQL Server database using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to a SQL server database using pyodbc in Python 3. But I get an error when I'm trying to establish the connection.

I do something like this:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=192.168.2.250;Database=DB;UID=username;PWD=password;')
```

And I get this:

```
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol][error:140B40C7:SSL routines:SSL_do_handshake:peer did not return a certificate] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Does anybody know how to solve this? The database is not my own, so I hope there is a solution that doesn't require changing any settings there.

I'm running Ubuntu within the Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Comment: To which version of SQL Server are you connecting? The error message suggests that it's a very old version, or not up-to-date with service packs or cumulative updates, if it's not supporting TLS 1.2 - that's what `ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol` is telling you. If you can't update the remote server you'll have to see if you can enable TLS 1.1 support in the OpenSSL cnf file inside WSL. TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 are disabled by default in modern stacks (and sometimes not even compiled in) because they're considered insecure.

Comment: SQL Server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP4) - 10.0.6241.0 (Intel X86)   Apr 17 2015 11:02:30   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition on Windows NT 6.0 <X86> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2) (VM) 

I tried enabling TLS 1.0 or 1.1 as described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/1112#issuecomment-609972220), but that did not solve the problem. Still the same error message.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 SP4 didn't [support TLS 1.2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe) until 10.0.6547.0. You should talk to the server's administrator about installing the TLS 1.2 update. Although SQL Server 2008 hasn't been supported by Microsoft for a number of years, now, you should urge them to upgrade to a newer supported version.

Comment: Even old encryption is better than no encryption at all. There is a certain method required to update the OpenSSL cnf file properly. Take a look at [my previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66454684/390122) to see if that helps you to enable TLS 1.1.

Answer (score 6):

There is a [breaking change](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228) in ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server

> Similar to the HTTP to HTTPS default changes made in web browsers a few years back (and the security reasons for them), we are changing the default value of the `Encrypt` connection option from `no` to `yes`/`mandatory`.

[ODBC Driver 18.0 for SQL Server Released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228)

So this

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=192.168.2.250;Database=DB;UID=username;PWD=password;')
```

is the same as

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=192.168.2.250;Database=DB;UID=username;PWD=password;Encrypt=yes')
```

If you don't want an encrypted connection you must opt out:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=192.168.2.250;Database=DB;UID=username;PWD=password;Encrypt=no')
```

> We also changed the behavior of TrustServerCertificate to not be tied to the Encrypt setting

So if your server is using a self-signed certificate, you also must opt out of certificate validation. so

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=192.168.2.250;Database=DB;UID=username;PWD=password;Encrypt=no;TrustServerCertificate=yes')
```

Comment: This seems like a good start. If I include `Encrypt=no`, the error gets a bit shorter: `OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')` (the last part with `SSL_do_handshake:peer did not return a certificate` is gone).

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error even with `Encrypt=no;TrustServerCertificate=yes`

Comment: SQL Server 2008 is out of support, so this might not be a working combination.  The older ODBC drivers are still available for download.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking my script out of WSL. Running the same command (with David's additions or `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` instead of 18) under Windows works without issues in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I used the pyodbc library, but kept getting errors. Using pymssql worked for me:

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(server='172.30.1.19')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

No need for port, username and password