# pyodbc.drivers() returns the list of drivers but my python script isn't running with any ODBC driver listed

Tags: python, sql-server, docker, odbc

Ran `print(pyodbc.drivers())` and it printed the list of available drivers... running a SQL container in docker I'm trying to manipulate the database from a python script

```
connector = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};' 'Server=cbbcb967dacb;' 'Database=testdb;' 'UID=sa;' 'PWD=Working@2022' 'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
connector.execute()

cursor = connector.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM inventory')

for i in cursor:
    print(i)
```

The error I get is:

> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].  (53) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (53)')

But the ODBC Driver is installed

Answer (score 0):

The exception suggests a network error, `cbbcb967dacb` looks like the hostname of the container, you might want to try its IP address directly or localhost if you ran SQL Server in docker as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash).

Are you able to `telnet cbbcb967dacb 1433` ?

Based on the discussion in the comments, if your docker container is running and was started as per the MSSQL tutorial, the following connection string should work:

```
"DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;UID=SA;PWD={Working@2022};DATABASE=testdb;"
```

Comment: not able to telnet so would I just put localhost as the server name and how would I get the IP address directly @ljmc

Comment: What operating system are you using ? Docker will have the information of the container in whatever interface you use. But again if you’ve used the same commands as the documentation, the container port 1433 is bridged to local 1433.

Comment: windows 10 @ljmc and yea I used the exact same documentation

Comment: See my edit, you should be able to connect on localhost, I put brackets around your password as I suspect it might need to be bracketed because of `@`, but I'm not entirely sure so try with and without them.

Comment: it doesn't give any problems besides "SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.\r\n" so client was unable to establish connection @ljmc

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be using an SSL connection, but you try putting back the trusted connection option. I use macos and linux and never needed to use anything else than the connection string I put for docker deployments of MSSQL.

Comment: If this is still not working you should make sure you can actually connect from within the container with the [following steps in tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver16&pivots=cs1-bash#connect-to-sql-server).

Comment: I can @ljmc but yeah even with trusted connection still doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71588236/2144390