# ssl handshake error when running dotnet ef database update command

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, ssl

I have added migrations script with `dotnet ef migrationsa add` successfully in my asp.net project.
I have Arch Linux,

Vs code about:

```
Version: 1.74.3
Commit: 97dec172d3256f8ca4bfb2143f3f76b503ca0534
Date: 2023-01-11T09:00:07.949Z
Electron: 19.1.9
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.0.10-arch2-1
Sandboxed: No
```

when I want to update database with :

```
dotnet ef database update -c PersistedGrantDbContext
```

I have below error:

> Build started...
> Build succeeded.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)
> ---> System.IO.IOException:  Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.EnableSsl(UInt32 options)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.TdsParserStateObjectManaged.EnableSsl(UInt32& info, Boolean tlsFirst)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.EnableSsl(UInt32 info, SqlConnectionEncryptOption encrypt, Boolean integratedSecurity) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(SqlConnectionEncryptOption encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean& marsCapable, Boolean& fedAuthRequired, Boolean tlsFirst) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean withFailover) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
> at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<Exists>b__0(DateTime giveUp) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.b__0(DbContext _, TState s)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
> ClientConnectionId:461d4248-1aeb-4d6c-8964-f7864a2468c9
> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)

this is my connection string and PersistedGrantDbContextFactory.cs

```
using Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.DbContexts;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace IdentityServer.Database
{
    public class PersistedGrantDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<PersistedGrantDbContext>
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration? _configuration;
        public PersistedGrantDbContextFactory()
        {
            _configuration = null;
        }
        public PersistedGrantDbContextFactory(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        PersistedGrantDbContext IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<PersistedGrantDbContext>.CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {           
            string? cs = _configuration.GetConnectionString("Identity01");
            string? assemblyName = typeof(PersistedGrantDbContextFactory).Assembly.GetName().Name;

            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<PersistedGrantDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(cs);

            IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                    .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                    {
                        options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(cs, sqlOptions =>
                        {
                            sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(assemblyName);
                        });
                    });

            optionsBuilder.UseApplicationServiceProvider(services.BuildServiceProvider());

            var context = new PersistedGrantDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
            return context;
        }
    }
}
```

My connection string :

```
"Data Source=ip,port;Initial Catalog=IdentityDb;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userName;Password=pass;Pooling=False;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;"
```

- I don't have any problem in with my deployed asp.net and it don't have problem with connection to database.
- I have this ssl error with `mssql` vs code extensions too

Comment: TLS is performed before an HTTP Request is sent to establish encryption keys.  The HTTP request will never be sent if TLS fails. With Net Library TLS was perform inside Net prior to version 4.7.2.  After 4.7.2 Net is performed by OS, but there is a option in the csproj that can still perform TLS in Net.  Many apps prior to 4.7.2 use OpenSSL for TLS because Net didn't support all the encryption modes.  OpenSSL is also use by non Net application for TLS in stead of OS.  There are too many combination for me to tell from this posting why some code works and others do not.

Comment: @jdweng what you need to know for solving this? tell me to provide it .because some days i have this problem

Comment: I gave you everything I know.  I do not know your versions, OS, OpenSSL.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66445221/5311735. Guess your sql server doesn't support TLS 1.2. That answer provides other options too.

Comment: Possibly a security proxy (e.g. Zscaler) may have blacklisted your SQL server and is blocking it by rejecting its SSL cert.

Answer (score 2):

i think you have to add `TrustServerCertificate=True` to your connection string which would look like this

"`VPMSSqlDbConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx-test-db;Integrated Security =true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=30;"`